# Ignore most updates

Tags: upgrade, manjaro

I am aware that Arch and derived distros recommend always keeping the system up to date, however I have chosen not to do this. I update occasionally, mostly if there is actually a problem I need to fix, and usually I update only the relevant packages, not all. That said, there are a handful of packages that I do want to stay up to date with.

I am using Manjaro, with Cinnamon as my DE. I constantly get the update notification about hundreds of updates, most of which I don't care about. `pacman -Syu` also results in a long list littered with irrelevant updates. I'd like to have a whitelist system: The update notifier should only tell me about updates to packages I've specifically marked as interesting. I should also be able to run a pacman command that will only update the packages on my whitelist, and their dependencies (but not notify me about dependency updates).

How can I do this?

Comment: Alternatively, you could comment out any active repositories in your package manager configuration; that way it won't see any updates and will always think you're up do date.

Comment: @DopeGhoti so, that would include security updates. It is perhaps not the smartest suggestion.

Comment: Neither is letting hundreds of updates accumulate in the first place.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Won't that prevent me from installing new software? Also, if it's not obvious, I do want to have the option of being able to run `pacman -Syu`, I just want a partial version of this command.

Comment: As for the updates accumulating, I get literally 100+ after a week, and since updating has a risk of breaking the system and requiring hours to fix, believe it or not I don't have the opportunity to update immediately every time I see the notification.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. This is not just a bad idea, it is antithetical to the way pacman works.

There are some corner cases where pacman will ignore *specific packages* (and you can use globbing to extend that), but to invert that concept and try to ignore the majority of packages would quickly result in two issues:

1. pacman would complain about dependency resolution problems during a partial upgrade and would be unable to complete the transaction. This would force you to re-edit your `pacman.conf` to make allowances--essentially turning package management into a manual task.
2. You would do a partial upgrade which would result in library incompatabilites and things would break.

The use case you describe is not suited *at all* to a rolling release. If you want this sort of approach, choose a distribution like Debian or Ubuntu LTS.